# How to export SnowFlake S3 data file to my AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake S3 data is in .txt.bz2, I need to export the data files present in this SnowFlake  S3 to my AWS S3, the exported results must be the same format as in the source location.This is wat I tried.

---

`COPY INTO @mystage/folder from 
(select $1||'|'||$2||'|'||  $3||'|'||   $4||'|'||   $5||'|'||$6||'|'||  $7||'|'||   $8||'|'|| $9||'|'|| $10||'|'||   $11||'|'||   $12||'|'||    $13||'|'||  $14||'|'||$15||'|'||    $16||'|'||  $17||'|'||$18||'|'||$19||'|'||  $20||'|'||  $21||'|'||  $22||'|'||  $23||'|'||  $24||'|'|| $25||'|'||26||'|'||  $27||'|'||  $28||'|'||  $29||'|'||  $30||'|'||  $31||'|'||  $32||'|'||  $33||'|'||  $34||'|'||  $35||'|'||  $36||'|'||  $37||'|'||  $38||'|'||    $39||'|'||    $40||'|'||  $41||'|'||  $42||'|'|| $43 
 from @databasename)
CREDENTIALS = (AWS_KEY_ID = '*****' AWS_SECRET_KEY = '*****' )
file_format=(TYPE='CSV' COMPRESSION='BZ2');
PATTERN='*/*.txt.bz2`

---

Comment: An a few years later, the COPY INTO command now does support BZ2 https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html

Answer (score 2):

Right now Snowflake does not support exporting data to file in bz2.

My suggestion is to set COMPRESSION='gzip', then you can export the Data to your S3 in gzip.

If exporting file in bz2 is high priority for you, please contact Snowflake support.

If you want to unload bz2 file from a Snowflake stage to your own S3, you can do something like this.

```
COPY INTO @myS3stage/folder from 
  (select $1||'|'||$2||'|'||  $3||'|'||   $4||'|'||   $5||'|'||$6||'|'||  $7||'|'||   $8||'|'|| $9||'|'|| $10||'|'||   $11||'|'||   $12||'|'||    $13||'|'||  $14||'|'||$15||'|'||    $16||'|'||  $17||'|'||$18||'|'||$19||'|'||  $20||'|'||  $21||'|'||  $22||'|'||  $23||'|'||  $24||'|'|| $25||'|'||26||'|'||  $27||'|'||  $28||'|'||  $29||'|'||  $30||'|'||  $31||'|'||  $32||'|'||  $33||'|'||  $34||'|'||  $35||'|'||  $36||'|'||  $37||'|'||  $38||'|'||    $39||'|'||    $40||'|'||  $41||'|'||  $42||'|'|| $43 
   from @snowflakeStage(PATTERN => '*/*.txt.bz2'))
CREDENTIALS = (AWS_KEY_ID = '*****' AWS_SECRET_KEY = '*****' )
file_format=(TYPE='CSV');
```

Comment: Thank you Jiaxing Liang, but I have solved this using a bash script, which exactly copies the .bz2 file from SF and dumps into s3 with credentials.